# Upload content from Mongoose DataBase to React Component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, mern

i'm having issues calling the database content(images) in my react component. Any help in how to call it?

I've been trying to upload pictures on my App, but i want to upload the pictures from the database and call them in the front end (react component) .

What i did was create the MERN App and created my mongoose model schema & it's route, also i created the database collection and connected my backend to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use multipart form data. And also you have to save the images in some location in your server or save it in cloud like amazon s3 for example and then store the image URL in your mongo db. Thats the good appraoch. You can find examples [here](https://github.com/jonjenkins/express-upload)